# How flatten struct | Serde

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I try to flatten this struct, but #[serde(flatten)] doesn't work as expected

Struct example:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct App {
 version: String,
 build_date: String,
 libraries: Vec<Library>
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Library {
 #[serde(flatten)] // give me a `panic` missing field `path`
 artifact: Artifact
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Artifact {
 path: String,
 url: String
}
```

Json file which I try to deserialize:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2a",
  "build_date": "2023/12/12",
  "libraries": [
     {
       "artifact": {
         "path": "somepath",
         "url": "someurl"
       }
     },
     {
       "artifact": {
         "path": "somepath",
         "url": "someurl"
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

What I'm get in result (rust struct)
P.S without #[serde(flatten)] it compiles, but I'm get this:

```rust
App {
  version: "0.2a",
  build_date: "2023/12/12",
  libraries: [
    Library {
      artifact: Artifact {
        path: "somepath",
        url: "someurl",
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

What I'm expect from `#[serde(flatten)]`
I want to remove `Artifact` parentness

```rust
App {
  version: "0.2a",
  build_date: "2023/12/12",
  libraries: [
    Library {
        path: "somepath",
        url: "someurl",
    },
  ]
}
```

How I can make this? #[serde(flatten)] not works for me. Maybe it's a bug? In official serde-docs example almost same with my json. But it's not working. Have any ideas how solve this issue?

Comment: What you are getting looks like the default `Debug` output and not JSON output - which would reflect the structure of your Rust types and not the serde representation.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, it's Debug output. But with serde(flatten) I'm get panic. Without serde(flatten), I'm get `Artifact` parentness (as expected from not flat structure), how I can remove `Artifact` parentness with serde?

Comment: As `serde` does not provide the `Debug` derive macro, it can't influence it's output, but your examples are `Debug` output.

Comment: @SamanthaEvans the JSON you provide corresponds to the data layout **without** `#[serde(flatten)]` so you should not use it. `Debug` output is only for developers eyes to begin with, if you want something different use `serde_json::to_string` or add a `Display` implementation to your liking.

Comment: @cafce25 I need to move fields from the Artifact structure inside the Library structure. Thus removing the parent (the Artifact structure)

Comment: But that's not how the JSON is structured, it clearly has an artifact object inside each library object. You can always either implement `De-/Serialize` yourself or create a second set of `App`/`Library` structs with `From<AppJson> for App` and `From<App> for AppJson`

Comment: @cafce25 Yes, it seems this is probably the closest solution to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is not flattened, so you shouldn't put `#[serde(flatten)]`. If you want the `Debug` to be flattened, you can impl it manually:

```rust
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct App {
    version: String,
    build_date: String,
    libraries: Vec<Library>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Library {
    artifact: Artifact,
}

impl fmt::Debug for Library {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.artifact.fmt(f)
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Artifact {
    path: String,
    url: String,
}
```

But note that `Debug` is for programmer-only output, not for user-facing output.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want the `flatten` attribute to have any effect, you have to make the JSON flattened. That means that the `artifact` key is replaced by its contents:

```
{
  "version": "0.2a",
  "build_date": "2023/12/12",
  "libraries": [
     {
       "path": "somepath",
       "url": "someurl"
     },
     {
       "path": "somepath",
       "url": "someurl"
     }
   ]
}
```